# GAE/PHP: How to disable https for wordpress?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I just installed wordpress as [described here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).
But I noticed that all the links in my blog are coming up as https. not just admin links. you can see here:
http://www.alephz.com/
the links to individual posts are https

how can I disable this? i don't want to purchase an ssl certificate now.

also, any insight why does this happens? is there a benefit to it?

Comment: the page served over http for me.

Comment: @StuartLangley the first page is http. but the links inside are https. for example to individual posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for this in wp-config.php

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
{
    $protocol_to_use = 'http://';
} else {
$protocol_to_use = 'https://';
}
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $protocol_to_use . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define( 'WP_HOME', $protocol_to_use . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

remove the $protocol_to_use stuff and change it to

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: it worked, thanks. about the admin pages, i removed every `secure: always` line from app.yaml, but still it gets redirected to https: http://www.alephz.com/wp-admin/

Comment: suggest u use secure pages for the admin pages if you can. Otherwise remove these lines in the app engine plugin: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-wordpress-plugin/blob/master/modules/core.php#L64

Answer (score 1):

Edit wp-config.php. There is a line that says:

```
`define( 'force_SSL', true );
```

Change that to

```
`define( 'force_SSL', false );
```

Comment: The location of the `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` option was important (I initially placed it at the end of `wp-config.php` and it did not work for me):

### Add it before the line - *important* :
```php
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Source:

https://www.pixelemu.com/documentation/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-enable-disable-ssl

Answer (score 0):

app.yaml: change all line

```
secure: always
```

to

```
secure: optional
```

or

```
secure: never
```

however, that won't be it fully: it's very possible that you're going to have same issues with the backend.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer, it's impossible to make any sense out of this.